# Atomic nearest neighbor notation

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, notation, crystals

I recently got a correction to a paper that I am writing. The correction references a section in which I talk about nearest neighbors. The comment says:

> Do you mean NN, NNN, etc., or NN, 2NN, 3NN? It's different.

To clarify: here is the (111) face of an FCC crystal with nearest neighbors numbered (sorry about the horrible mouse-written numbers):

[image: FCC(111) Nearest neighbors]

Starting from the center, I would denote the nearest neighbors as NN, 2NN, 3NN, etc. just as they are numbered. I think it would be the same to call them NN, NNN, NNNN, etc. Does anyone here know what this reviewer could be talking about? Because this seems like a simple concept to me and I have never encountered any confusion with the notation before.

Comment: Can you include the text section from your paper that is under discussion?

Comment: It wouldn't make a damn lick of sense, but I have seen the notation NN, NNN, etc. referring to two-nucleon, three-nucleon, etc. interactions in an EFT context. Otherwise I've definitely seen both notations in condensed matter, with the NN,2NN,3NN,etc... notation being much more common.

Answer (score 1):

hmm this is usually the standard notation with
\begin{align*}
\text{NN} &= \text{NN}\\
\text{NNN} &= \text{2NN}\\
&\ldots
\end{align*}
The only thing I could imagine is some kind of numbering of the nearest neighbors: If you have 5 nearest neighbors like in your example with 1NN, 2NN, 3NN, etc. you could mean the first atom which is NN, the second atom which is NN and so on. Nonetheless that would be really weird, but I dont see any other meaning of these abbreviations in a physics context.

Comment: I believe that NNN means "next-nearest neighbour" in this context.